# Not able to execute classes through Maven test with Testng.xml file in terminal, but working in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, saucelabs

I'm not able to execute the *testng.xml* file through Maven in the terminal integrated with Sauce Labs, but I'm getting my solution running through *testng suit* in the Eclipse console.

**I'm getting the following output on the terminal:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Oct 19, 2018 2:06:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Selected Mattress from header
Oct 19, 2018 2:06:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake c 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Selected Mattress from header
Oct 19, 2018 2:08:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Selected Mattress from header
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 
125.596 sec - in TestSuite

**Results:**

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:22 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-19T14:08:28+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I'm getting the following output through the Eclipse console. I want the same solution through the terminal:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Oct 19, 2018 2:44:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Selected Mattress from header
Selected Mattress option from menu
ATC button Clicked
Popup closed
Checkout 
FirstName entered
LastName entered
Emailid entered
Telephone number entered
AddAddressManualy link clicked
Billing Information completed: achetez le matelas et les produits eve - Panier | eve Matelas
Delivery completed: achetez le matelas et les produits eve - Panier | eve Matelas
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Redirect to paypal Done: achetez le matelas et les produits eve - Panier | eve Matelas
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payment Completed: PayPal Checkout - Review your payment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oct 19, 2018 2:47:02 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Selected Mattress from header
Selected Mattress option from menu
ATC button Clicked
Popup closed
Checkout 
FirstName entered
LastName entered
Emailid entered
Telephone number entered
AddAddressManualy link clicked
Billing Information completed: achetez le matelas et les produits eve - Panier | eve Matelas
Delivery completed: achetez le matelas et les produits eve - Panier | eve Matelas
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Redirect to Card Payment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Card Payment Completed: bravo ! bienvenue dans la famille eve matelas | eve Matelas
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Show the cmd you used in terminal and its output.

Comment: Command I used in terminal is mvn clean test

Comment: How do you print those lines? System.out? or any logging framework? It may be about the logging level configuration. Since the "Tests run: 3" mentions that the test classes was executed, the printing may be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved now we need to Configure Xml file in POM file:

```js
<configuration>  
   <suiteXmlFiles>    
       <suitXmlFile>src/main/resources/FileName.xml</suitXmlFile>   
   </suiteXmlFiles> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from terminal, you have to do

```
mvn clean install
```

By default above will run default xml given in your pom. If you want to run too many testng.xml and it is expecting some parameters, try below

```
mvn clean install -DA=A1

A= string defined in your pom
A1 is value to it.
```